# Creating outline around layer which has separated features using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dissolve

I have a layer representing a neighborhood. And the roads are separating groups of features(blocks) from each other. I want an outline around the whole neighborhood and not around each feature or each block. I want a line around the whole layer. I have tried dissolving, masking and merging. None have worked.

How could I do this using ArcGIS Desktop?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use a concave hull?

Comment: vinh I don't know what that is... could you please guide me?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Advanced level license, the Aggregate Polygons tool will do the heavy lifting:

[image]

Remaining holes are easy to fix by hand, alternatively apply this field calculator expression on field "Shape" of output:

```
arcpy.Polygon(!Shape!.getPart(0))
```

[image]